# How to store the result of the FontDialog.Font Property in a Text file

Tags: c#, fonts

I am trying to give the user a menu option to save a text file with preferences in it for the font he/she chooses and the color of the text inside the textbox.

This is the code I am using. and ms visual studio 2015 tells me

> cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "System.Drawing.Font"

So obviously I need another type of variable that will convert to `System.Drawing.Font`. I even tried String and that didn't work either.

```
private void loadPreferencesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender,  EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog2.FileName);
            var myFont= sr.ReadLine();
            var myColor = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            fontDialog1.Font = myFont;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're reading a string from settings file and then setting the Font property to a string. Set it to the Font class, i.e. `fontDialog1.Font = new Font(myFont, fontSize:20);`

Answer (score 0):

Larry,

You did not show us the code you have to store the font and color into the file you open with openFileDialog2, but that structure is important. I am going to assume you simply saved the ToString of the font and color to the file.

Your file might look like this:

> [Font: Name=Segoe UI, Size=8.25, Units=3, GdiCharSet=0,
>   GdiVerticalFont=False]
>
> Color [Black]

Your code will have to parse the strings to turn them back into a font and a color. 
The code for parsing the font will require you to split the string up, reading name and values which you will use to create a new font. The same applies for the color; you will have to parse the string from the reader into (In my example) a color string (E.G. Black).

> var myFont = new Font(fontName, fontSize);
>
> var myColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colorName);

fontName, fontSize and colorName are variables you will have to create and then fill from the stream.

HTH,

Marc